# HTTrack on angular.io

Tags: angular, web-crawler, httrack

I was trying to use HTTrack with default settings to download the angular io docs - without any success.

What options and preferences should I use for preforming this task?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to git clone the https://github.com/angular/angular.git repository.

Navigate to the aio file and install the modules with yarn.